# Creating dictionary in Python using a variable

Tags: syntax

Using following method to create a dictionary:

```
>>> dict(name = 'Joe')
{'name': 'Joe'}
```

What if I already had a variable `name` with a value 'Joe' and wanted to use it as a key in the dictionary?
Python picks the first argument and transforms it into a string.
Why it's not:

```
>>> dict('name' = 'Joe')
{'name': 'Joe'}
```

That is, why doesn't it require quotes for generating a dictionary with a string key, and treats `name` as a variable otherwise?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @JohnD: actually trying to understand why the dict() accepts a string without quotes... Other methods that expect a str won't let you go away with it.

Comment: yeah `dict(2=1)` gives SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="? So that is undefined behavior, python happens to treat it as a string but it's not something you should count on. Just do it the way my answer described and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

When using `dict(name = 'Joe')`, the `name` is not passed as a variable but instead as a parameter to the function `dict`.

If you want to use a variable as a key, you can use:

```py
name = 'joe'
dict[name] = 'joe'
```

which will result in a dictionary `{'joe': 'joe'}`

Answer (score -1):

Use `{}` instead of `dict()` if you are tryna initialize a python dictionary with key-value pairs.

```py
>>> name = 'Joe'
>>> my_dict = {name: 3}
{'Joe': 3}
>>> my_dict['name'] = 5
>>> my_dict
{'Joe': 3, 'name': 5}
```

will use the value of the variable `name`.